# JavaScript multiple array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I would like to create this array in Javascript, but i am actually struck in the process. I have given an example below:

I am facing a very big problem in generating the second array of the 'product' list object. Could any of you please advise me how I can generate multiple product lists like what has been done below.

```
var dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push({
         'products': [{
             'name': 'FTP',
             'id': 'TXN_987666',
             'price': 123,
             'brand': 'ABC',
             'category': 'RTP',
             'quantity': '4'
         }, {
             'name': 'CHI',
             'id': 'TXN_89798798',
             'price': 656,
             'brand': 'Fairmont',
             'category': 'FMP',
             'quantity': 7
         }]
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Remove 2 `}` at the end, you have syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of extra braces at the end of your .push() statement. Try this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dataLayer = [];
        dataLayer.push({
            'products': [{
                'name': 'FTP',
                'id': 'TXN_987666',
                'price': 123,
                'brand': 'ABC',
                'category': 'RTP',
                'quantity': '4'
         }, {
                'name': 'CHI',
                'id': 'TXN_89798798',
                'price': 656,
                'brand': 'Fairmont',
                'category': 'FMP',
                'quantity': 7
         }]
        });
         // Test the object contents --
         // Click arrows to expand the array members in the console
        console.log(dataLayer);
    </script>
```